# Extract HTML and search in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am still a beginner at python and I was experimenting.

I am looking for a way to request a url and get the data of the webpage so the page does not need to open.

Once I get the data, I need to search the data for a tag, for example, if it has 'hello' somewhere on the home page that is requested.

Here is an example:

```
import urllib.request
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()

x = mystr.find('testing word tag');

print(x)
```

Please bear with me as I am still a rookie and can't find an example of what I am looking for.

^ found this code on here but it does not seem to work to find a string.

Anyone knows the best way to do it?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Web-scrapping _de-facto_ use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/doc)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the most used libraries for this kind of work:

[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to get the HTML of the page.

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) to find elements (and much more)

```
$ pip install requests bs4
```

And in your favorite IDE:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.python.org")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

sometag = soup.find("sometag")
print(sometag)
```

Comment: Or simply as an extension for OP's existing script: `soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr);
soup.find("sometag")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import requests
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577634/extract-html-and-search-in-python"

res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?

Comment: You get the html of that webpage. If you want to extract tags easier you could use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req
html = req.get('https://www.python.org')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
title = doc.getElement('title').text
print (title)
title = doc.getElementByText('Welcome to', tag='title').text
print (title)
```

Result:

```
Welcome to Python.org
Welcome to Python.org
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples